# SpringData Elasticsearch JSON Array to Java List

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Using spring-data-elasticsearch in version 2.2.0 (+ project lombok)

I want to deserialize a JSON response to a Java class. Every field/object except for an JSON array works fine. The Java list "bs" which should contain the B objects from the JSON array stays null.

The JSON response with the array looks like this:

```
        ...
        "_index": "someIndex",
        "_type": "A",
        "_id": "someId",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
           ...
           "bs": [
              {
                 "number": "0000000001234",
                 "type": "03"
              },
              {
                 "number": "4008123694567",
                 "type": "13"
              }
           ],
           ...
        }
        ...
```

The JSON array "bs" should be deserialized to the Java list bs. The Java class A which contains a list of Bs looks like this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "#{AIndexType.getIndexName()}", type = "#{AIndexType.getTypeName()}")
public class A implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<B> bs;
}
```

Class B looks like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class B implements Serializable {

    private String number;

    private String type;
}
```

Using the @Field annotation with FieldType.NESTED doesn't seem to work/make any difference to not using it.
Do I have to write a custom deserializer (for the list bs) or is there any other way to get this working?

Comment: Could you include the output or stacktrace when you deserialize the json array?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The problem is solved, there was a link (/wrong use of properties) to another elasticsearch instance which actually had no instances of B.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above.

The problem is solved, there was a link (/wrong use of properties) to another elasticsearch instance which actually had no instances of B.